# objZkeeper = new ZkemClient(RaiseDeviceEvent); throw an Exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022, zkemkeeper

In my ASP.Net web core MVC when debugging into "objZkeeper = new ZkemClient(RaiseDeviceEvent);" the visual studio throw an Exception: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

The whole code that i put in a HomeController as a ActionResult when click a button.
I've put all dll files to system32  and SystemWOW64, add a COM Refernce with DLL from systemWOW64, run public static bool Is64BitProcess { get; } and get my Project is 32bit. But nothing helped. I run the BiomatrixCore Project in C# window form and that work fine.
Why ASP.Net web core MVC threw that Exception? Did i đo wrong?

Comment: Just run debug in x86 CPU and everything works fine